# Можно задать ширину предка-предка?

Tags: css, sass

имею такую структуру:

```
<div id="lev-1">
    <div id="lev-2">
        <div id="lev-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#lev-2 { position: absolutle; }
```

можно ли для `lev-3` установить ту же ширину, что и `lev-1`

`UPDATE`

требуется выставить ширину для верхнего скролла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас вопрос явно неполный, условия не все озвучены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, если поддержка IE не важна (ответ и для ширины, и для высоты).

Задайте блоку `#lev-1` любой `transform` (например, `tranform: rotate(0deg)` который визуально ничего не поменяет), а для `#lev3` комбинацию `position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;` (или вместо `width: 100%; height: 100%;` задайте `right: 0; bottom: 0;`). Демонстрция:

```css
#lev-1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  
  /* необязательные стили для демонстрации */
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#lev-2 {
  position: absolute;
  
  /* необязательные стили для демонстрации */
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#lev-3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* необязательные стили для демонстрации */
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="lev-1">
  <div id="lev-2">
    <div id="lev-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это работает, потому что так следует из спецификации [CSS Transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering):

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

Что в вольном переводе значит:

> Для элементов, параметры которых регулируются блочной моделью CSS, любое значение `transform`, отличное от `none` приводит к созданию контекста наложения и содержащего их блока. Объект выступает в качестве контейнера для потомков с фиксированным позиционированием.